# Recomposition while using rememberCoroutineScope

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I am using a Coroutine Scope inside a callback for navigation icon selection. But whenever the screen recompose, this icon is also getting recomposed because of the coroutine scope used in the callback.

But if i use a state variable and update the LaunchedEffect, it is skipping the recomposition.

A sample code for both case is given below: (Compose Version: 1.3.1)

Case 1: MethodTwo gets recomposed on every recomposition of MethodOne.

```
@Composable
fun MethodOne() {
   val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

   MethodTwo(onClick = {
     scope.launch { //viewmodel actions }
   })


@Composable
fun MethodTwo(onClick: () -> Unit) {
   //UI
}
```

Case 2: MethodTwo skips the recomposition on every recomposition of MethodOne.

```
@Composable
fun MethodOne() {
   var toggle = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

   LaunchedEffect(toggle) {
      //viewmodel actions
   }

   MethodTwo(onClick = {
     toggle = true
   })


@Composable
fun MethodTwo(onClick: () -> Unit) {
   //UI
}
```

Is anyone facing the same issue? Is there any workaround or am i missing something on recomposition?

Comment: What is your question exactly? Like do you want to know why the first approach recomposes and the second don't?

Comment: Yes. Also, the first method is preferred one from the official doc. How do i stop recomposition in the first case?